# SQL Stored Procedure - Understanding SQL Statement

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

New to stored procedures. Can anyone explain the following SQL sample which appears at the start of a stored procedure?

Begin/End - Encloses a series of SQL statements so that a group of SQL statements can be executed

SET NOCOUNT ON - the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a SQL statement) is not returned.

DECLARE - setting local variables

While - loops round

With - unsure

Update batch  - unsure

SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT; - unsure

```
    BEGIN
             SET NOCOUNT ON;

--UPDATE, done in batches to minimise locking
             DECLARE @Batch INT= 100;
             DECLARE @Rowcount INT= @Batch;
             WHILE @Rowcount > 0
                 BEGIN
                     WITH t
                          AS (
                          SELECT [OrganisationID],
                                 [PropertyID],
                                 [QuestionID],
                                 [BaseAnsweredQuestionID]
                          FROM dbo.Unioned_Table
                          WHERE organisationid = 1),
                          s
                          AS (
                          SELECT [OrganisationID],
                                 [PropertyID],
                                 [QuestionID],
                                 [BaseAnsweredQuestionID]
                          FROM dbo.table
                          WHERE organisationid = 1),
                          batch
                          AS (
                          SELECT TOP (@Batch) T.*,
                                              s.BaseAnsweredQuestionID NewBaseAnsweredQuestionID
                          FROM T
                               INNER JOIN s ON t.organisationid = s.organisationid
                                               AND t.PropertyID = s.PropertyID
                                               AND t.QuestionID = s.QuestionID
                          WHERE t.BaseAnsweredQuestionID <> s.BaseAnsweredQuestionID)
                          UPDATE batch
                            SET
                                BaseAnsweredQuestionID = NewBaseAnsweredQuestionID
                     SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
                 END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the comment `--UPDATE, done in batches to minimise locking`.

The intent is to update `dbo.table`'s column `BaseAnsweredQuestionID` with the equivalent column from `dbo.Unioned_Table`, in batches of 100. The comment suggests the batching logic is necessary to prevent locking.

In detail:

`DECLARE @Batch INT= 100;` sets the batch size.

`DECLARE @Rowcount INT= @Batch;` initializes the loop.
`WHILE @Rowcount > 0` starts the loop. @`Rowcount` will become zero when the update statement affects no rows (see below).

`with a as ()` is a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (commonly abbreviated to CTE) - it creates a temporary result set which you can effectively treat as a table. The next few queries define CTEs `t`, `s` and `batch`.

CTE batch contains just 100 rows by using the `SELECT TOP (@Batch)` term - it selects a random 100 rows from the two other CTEs.

The next statement:

```
UPDATE batch
   SET BaseAnsweredQuestionID = NewBaseAnsweredQuestionID
SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

updates the 100 rows in the batch CTE (which in turn is a join on two other CTEs), and populates the loop variable @Rowcount with the number of rows affected by the update statement (@@ROWCOUNT). If there are no matching rows, @@ROWCOUNT becomes zero, and thus the loop ends.

Comment: A SQL Server table will see a **lock escalation** (from using individual row-level locks to an exclusive **table lock**) when a single transaction uses *more than 5000** locks.